# Null values & logical operators not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out why if I enter null values, the alert still appears when it shouldn’t. the argument states that all values must not be null otherwise the function should end.

Does anyone have any ideas? thank you!

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 height:1000px;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 margin:0;
}

.divider{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background:#CCC;
 display:block;
 margin:10px;
}

h2{
 font-size:16px;
 display:block;
}
#confirm-paragraph{}
#global-variable-paragraph{}
#user-input{}
#expressions{}
#elephant-paragraph{}
#method-1{}
#method-2{}
#ml{}
#litres{}
#conditional-operator{}
#cast-1{}
#cast-2{}
```

```html
<!-- Checklist: Obtain user input and store it in variables -->
<!-- Report variable text to the client window -->
<!-- Prompt -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>User Input Variables Example</h2>
<button onclick="nameFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="user-input">This text should change after clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version3!!!!!!!!</p>
<p>Should not alert if null values are present - null values are present by just clicking OK when entering nothing. All values should not be null in order for the alert to appear</p>
<script>
function nameFunction() {
 var yourforename = prompt("What is your first name?");
 var yoursurname = prompt("What is your last name?");
 var yourage = prompt("What is your age?");

 if (yourforename != null && yoursurname != null && yourage != null) {
 alert("Hello " + yourforename + " " + yoursurname + ". You are " + yourage + " years old.");
 }
}
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: Pretty sure if you don't input anything in `prompt`, it returns an empty string and not null. Also, you can remove your CSS/HTML code and remove the tags for both languages too as they're not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it is a confusion over the return value.  If you type nothing in the prompt, then the empty string (`""`) is returned.  However, if you click the cancel button, then `null` is returned.  Your code is only checking for not `null`.  `""` is not equal to `null`, so the pass checks.  A quick fix could be to change

```
if (yourforename != null && yoursurname != null && yourage != null) {
    alert("Hello " + yourforename + " " + yoursurname + ". You are " + yourage + " years old.");
    }
```

to

```
if (yourforename && yoursurname && yourage) {
    alert("Hello " + yourforename + " " + yoursurname + ". You are " + yourage + " years old.");
    }
```

Comment: You don't want the prefix `!` operator in the corrected version.

Comment: Good catch! I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you alert the `typeof yourforename` variable etc... You will see that it returns a string. So if you rewrite your if statement as so:

```
var yourforename = prompt("What is your first name?");
var yoursurname = prompt("What is your last name?");
var yourage = prompt("What is your age?");

if (yourforename > '' && yoursurname > '' && yourage > '') {
  alert("Hello " + yourforename + " " + yoursurname + ". You are " + yourage + " years old.");
}
```

It will work. Because you're now checking if the length of the string is bigger than an empty `''`.